# Command not found when trying to start Linux Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a Bash script that I have been using for a while called `launch.sh`.  This script launches a set of processes and the script looks like:

```
for ch in job_lists/*; do
  merlin mkt -log 30 -rollList $ch > "output_$(basename $ch)" &
done
```

The script pickups a set of 6 jobs from the `job_lists` and then executes line 2 where another script `merlin` is called. When I launch the script I get the following returned to the console:

[image]

I looks like it picks up the 6 jobs (hence the 6 lines of output), but I think it can't find merlin....

I've just moved my environment to a new laptop and copied over all my scripts. The merlin script is there and I have tried `chmod +x launch.sh` and `chmod +x merlin.sh` without success. I have even tried adding `#!/bin/bash` at top of the script without success.

merlin is located at:

[image]

I have checked my PATH (see below), I may have missed something but it looks like the PATH to merlin (home/scoleman/user/bin) is present.

[image]

Comment: Where is merlin? Probably a stupid question but have you checked that it's in your $PATH?

Comment: `merlin` != `merlin.sh`

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the path of the script.

Try this :

```
for ch in job_lists/*; do
    ./merlin.sh mkt -log 30 -rollList $ch > "output_$(basename $ch)" &
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that your merlin.sh script is not in the executing users PATH. Either add the script to a place that your path already points to, add the directory where your script lives to your PATH, or specify the full path to the script from the launch.sh script.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the merlin has execution permission, if not set it by,

   chmod +x merlin
2. Make sure the merlin script is residing in the same location as the launch.sh, if not give the correct path to the merlin command,

```
for ch in job_lists/*; do   
<PATH_TO_MERLIN>/merlin mkt -log 30 -rollList $ch > "output_$(basename $ch)" & 
done
```

or add the merlin location to the PATH environmental variable.

```
export PATH=$PATH:<PATH_TO_MERLIN>
```

Answer (score 0):

run it without extention maybe it works,.